# Proper method of getting a server auth access token for a client to use with google analytics

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-analytics-api

I have a global account that has several views that I want to use on the server side to embed dashboards for the various views on the client side. From what I understand, I get an access token using a service account on the server side and can then send the access token to the client side whenever needed. I was wondering, is this the correct flow? Should the access token be per session?

The authorization on the client side shown [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/component-reference?hl=en) has a field for a server auth access token, but couldn't find documentation on the exact flow I wanted. Basically I'm unsure what the proper way of generating that server auth access token is. Any help/pointers would be very much appreciated.

Comment: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/server-side-authorization/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here][1] is an example of how to set up server side auth. The above code creates a new token when anyone visits the site. You can see the endpoint that gets that access token [here][2].

Below are the general steps to get to a working version:

**Step 1**: Create a service account and download the JSON key

**Step 2**: Add the service account as a user in Google Analytics

**Step 3**: Use the JSON key data to request an access token

```
# service-account.py

import json
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

# The scope for the OAuth2 request.
SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'

# The location of the key file with the key data.
KEY_FILEPATH = 'path/to/json-key.json'

# Load the key file's private data.
with open(KEY_FILEPATH) as key_file:
  _key_data = json.load(key_file)

# Construct a credentials objects from the key data and OAuth2 scope.
_credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
    _key_data['client_email'], _key_data['private_key'], SCOPE)

# Defines a method to get an access token from the credentials object.
# The access token is automatically refreshed if it has expired.
def get_access_token():
  return _credentials.get_access_token().access_token
```

Back to the client side:

**Step 4**: Load the Embed API library.

```
<script>
(function(w,d,s,g,js,fs){
  g=w.gapi||(w.gapi={});g.analytics={q:[],ready:function(f){this.q.push(f);}};
  js=d.createElement(s);fs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  js.src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
  fs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fs);js.onload=function(){g.load('analytics');};
}(window,document,'script'));
</script>
```

**Step 5**: Add HTML containers to host the dashboard components.

```
<div id="chart-1-container"></div>
<div id="chart-2-container"></div>
```

**Step 6**: Write the dashboard code.

Use the access token obtained in step 3 to authorize the Embed API.

gapi.analytics.ready(function() {

      /**
       * Authorize the user with an access token obtained server side.
       */
      gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
        'serverAuth': {
          'access_token': '{{ ACCESS_TOKEN_FROM_SERVICE_ACCOUNT }}'
        }
      });
      ...


The additional work of creating an endpoint which returns the token depends on your back end implementation but the source code of how the demo does it can be found [here][2].


  [1]: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/server-side-authorization/
  [2]: https://github.com/googleanalytics/ga-dev-tools/blob/abb3c5a18160327a38bf5c7f07437dc402569cac/lib/controllers/server_side_auth.py

Comment: I'm trying to port service-account.py to Google Auth PHP Library, it's the right tool?

Comment: It depends on everything you are trying to accomplish, but [this example might help](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-php)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with Google Analytics, but as far as OAuth goes, the handling of access tokens and refresh tokens should all be on the server-side. The client receives an authorization code and provides that to the server, which then obtains the tokens and uses the tokens to obtain the data necessary. There shouldn't be any need to send an access token to the client.

It might be helpful to read this, which describes the standard OAuth flow:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: If my response does not answer Cenoc's question, then I do not understand what Cenoc is asking. My interpretation of what Cenoc is asking is whether or not getting an access token and sending it to the client is the correct OAuth flow, and also if the access tokens are on a per-session basis. I explain in my response that Cenoc's flow is incorrect and rather that access tokens and refresh tokens should be all on the server-side, which makes the second question irrelevant. If the question I have answered is not the question the author intended to ask, then perhaps more clarification is needed.